# How to code OTHERS response in excel using ISNUMBER and SEARCH or any other function?

Tags: excel, survey

=IF(COUNT(FIND({"Saving","Bank fixed deposit","Public provident fund","National saving certificate","Post-office saving","Government security"},A2)),"FALSE","TRUE"). I tried this formula but it returns false when the OTHERS value is present with the values mentioned above.

Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question, use comments instead

Comment: Could you please include a sample table in your question?